# Add custom severity inside a Ruby logger formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

Is it possible to get a custom severity from my `Logger::Formatter`?
For example, I need my severity to be, sometimes, equal to 'TRACE':

```
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   severity == 'TRACE' ? msg : "#{severity} #{msg}"
end
```

Is it doable ? 
I am not sure if I need to override the `Severity` module or the `SEV_LABEL`or something else...

Comment: No, this does not explain how to override ::Logger Labels and Severities to be used in the formatter.

Comment: @Arkon I believe the nominated exemplar does explain how to create a custom severity ("log level" is the same thing as "severity").  I'll close this as a duplicate.  If that's incorrect, please edit the question to more clearly explain what it is you want to do.